# JSOUP using Nodes to get specific text that is outside HTML tags

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup, nodes

So, I've been using jSoup to parse a website for some metaData, which works great. The problem is that some of the important metaData that I need is not within any tags, and I don't know how to get it.

Here is an example of the data I would need to get from my URL:

```
<div class="newclass ">
        <div>
            <p>     
                    <strong>Arist:</strong>&nbsp;Picasso Biggie <em>|</em>
                    <strong>Released:</strong>&nbsp;3 years ago <em>|</em>
                    <strong>Album:</strong>&nbsp;Picasso Biggie: The Big OneUp <em>|</em>                       
                    <strong>Producer:</strong>&nbsp;Various <em>|</em>                      
                    <strong>Featuring:</strong>&nbsp;Mount Kimbie <em>|</em>                                        
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

What I would be looking for in the html here are things like the artist "Picasso Biggie", the year it was released "3 years ago", and album "Picasso Biggie: The Big OneUp" etc....
I've looked into using nodes with jSoup, but I can only find a few examples and cannot figure out how to get jSoup to do what I'm looking for in particular.

This is the code I've tried and it returns nothing:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get;
Elements dakss1 = doc.select(".newclass ");
for(Element dakss : rayz1) { 
     TextNode quill = (TextNode) rayz1.nextSibling().childNode(0);
     System.out.println("" + quill);
}
```

**UPDATE:** The answer by [Shaowei Ling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318602/jsoup-using-child-nodes-to-get-specific-text-not-wrapped-within-tags/22326929#22326929) works great for getting all of the text outside of the tags, but I am wondering is there a way to specify only specific nodes, so I can only get specific words. For example instead of getting

```
    Picasso Biggie
    3 years ago
    Picasso Biggie: The Big OneUp
    Various
    Mount Kimbie
```

I only get:

```
3 years ago
```

if all I need is just the year the album was released?

**UPDATE #2:** 
Okay, to solve my second problem where I was parsing multiple items with the same HTML structure as above, I just went ahead and included the specific element I wanted in my selector query for jSoup. So, for example if I wanted to get the all the release dates for Picasso Biggies albums. This is the code I used:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get;
    Elements dakss1 = doc.select(".newclass p strong:contains(Released) ");
    for(Element dakss : dakss1) { 
         Node nodeWithReleaseDates =(Node) dakss.nextSibling();;
         System.out.println("" + nodeWithReleaseDates);
    }
```

This went ahead and returned all the release dates I wanted for Picasso Biggie's various albums, as follows:

```
3 years ago
2 years ago 
7 months ago
1 month ago
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question, there is an undefined variable `rayz1`.

The example code may help you. I have run it, it works.

```
    String html = 
            "<div class=\"newclass \">\n"
            + "        <div>\n"
            + "            <p>     \n"
            + "                    <strong>Arist:</strong>&nbsp;Picasso Biggie <em>|</em>\n"
            + "                    <strong>Released:</strong>&nbsp;3 years ago <em>|</em>\n"
            + "                    <strong>Album:</strong>&nbsp;Picasso Biggie: The Big OneUp <em>|</em>                       \n"
            + "                    <strong>Producer:</strong>&nbsp;Various <em>|</em>                      \n"
            + "                    <strong>Featuring:</strong>&nbsp;Mount Kimbie <em>|</em>                                        \n"
            + "            </p>\n"
            + "        </div>\n"
            + "</div>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements dakss1 = doc.select("div p strong");
    for (Node dakss : dakss1) {
        System.out.println(dakss.nextSibling().toString().replace("&nbsp;", "").trim());
    }
```

The result would be:

```
    Picasso Biggie
    3 years ago
    Picasso Biggie: The Big OneUp
    Various
    Mount Kimbie
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to go about that. Now, if I wanted to get specific text like only the artist "Picasso Biggie" and none of the other text would that even be possible?

Comment: @KellaRoss,for more details, you can refer the [jsoup tutorial](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/).Then,if you only need the first one, you can try `Node nodeYouWant =((Node)dakss1.first()).nextSibling();`

Comment: I'm a little confused... I understand now that I  need a node to grab text that is outside of the tag. However, I can't figure out how to grab any other text that I want. What I mean by this is when I use the code `Node nodeYouWant =((Node)dakss1.first()).nextSibling();`, it gives me `Picasso Biggie`, but I can't seem to find a way to select a different line such as Release date so that I can get `3 years ago` My modified code that I have been using `Node nodeYouWant =((Node)dakss1.get(3)).nextSibling();` doesn't work here because the I'm parsing metaData for numerous albums.

Comment: @KellaRoss, If you want the date, you can try `Node nodeYouWant=((Node)dakss1.get(1)).nextSibling();`, which will bring you the second value `3 years ago`.

Comment: I understand that part, however if I am parsing multiple albums, all with metaData like the the html code I provided above, whenever I use the `get` method in `(Node)dakss1.get(1)).nextSibling();` I only get the release date for one album and not the others. So if Picasso Biggie has another album from `2 years ago` or even `2 months ago` I only get the 1st release date for the 1st album which is `3 years ago` I cannot find a way to get all the release dates for all the different albums in an Array or List?

Comment: @KellaRoss, sorry, I just get your meaning. However, you should give the explicit html code structure of how these albums organize. Then we can find other ways to parsing dates of all albums.If you don't mind, could you share me a sample html link?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem, which can be found in my 2nd update. The html would have just been a copy of what I provided above, with a new `<div class="newclass ">` containing metaData for the different albums.

Comment: @KellaRoss, Congratulations.you didn't describe the `<div class="newclass">`(another possible situations are `<div>` or `<p>`) as the beginning for each album. so I ask you for the page structure.